# fullcalendar why are events not showing on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have a fullcalendar that is working fine on laptops and android phone
but when i try on iphones its working fine except its not showing events

can any one give me any hint please
this is the code

```
        var host = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host
        fetch(`${host}/api/courses/get_bookings/?profile=${profile_pk}`, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
                },
            })
            .then(function(result) {
                return result.json();
            })
            .then(function(data) {

                if (data.error) {
                    var errorMsg = document.getElementById("calendar-error");
                    errorMsg.innerHTML = data.error;

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        errorMsg.innerHTML = "";

                    }, 20000);
                } else {

                    /* initialize the calendar
                    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
                    let bookings = data.results

                    console.log('bookings', bookings)
                    let events = []
                    for (let b of bookings) {
                        // var isWeekend = false
                        let date = b.date
                            // while (start_at != b.end_at) {


                        let my_start = date + ' ' + b.period.start_at
                        let myend_at = date + ' ' + b.period.end_at


                        my_start = Date.parse(my_start)
                        myend_at = Date.parse(myend_at)
                        my_start = new Date(my_start)
                        var dayOfWeek = my_start.getDay();
                        // isWeekend = (dayOfWeek === 6) || (dayOfWeek === 0); // 6 = Saturday, 0 = Sunday
                        // if (!isWeekend) {
                        console.log('b.course.name', b.course.name)
                        console.log('b.course.my_start', my_start)
                        console.log('new Date(myend_at)', new Date(myend_at))
                        events.push({
                                title: b.course.name,
                                start: my_start,
                                end: new Date(myend_at),
                                allDay: false,
                                className: 'important'
                            })
                            // }





                    }
                    console.log('events', events)
                        //              center: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',

                    var calendar = null
                    var date = new Date();
                    var d = date.getDate();
                    var m = date.getMonth();
                    var y = date.getFullYear();
                    calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                        header: {
                            left: 'title',
                            center: 'agendaDay,month',
                            right: 'prev,next today'
                        },
                        editable: true,
                        firstDay: 1, //  1(Monday) this can be changed to 0(Sunday) for the USA system
                        // selectable: true,
                        defaultView: 'month',

                        axisFormat: 'h:mm',
                        columnFormat: {
                            month: 'ddd', // Mon
                            week: 'ddd d', // Mon 7
                            day: 'dddd M/d', // Monday 9/7
                            agendaDay: 'dddd d'
                        },
                        titleFormat: {
                            month: 'MMMM yyyy', // September 2009
                            week: "MMMM yyyy", // September 2009
                            day: 'MMMM yyyy' // Tuesday, Sep 8, 2009
                        },
                        allDaySlot: false,
                        selectHelper: true,
                        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                            if (title) {
                                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                                        title: title,
                                        start: start,
                                        end: end,
                                        allDay: allDay
                                    },
                                    true // make the event "stick"
                                );
                            }
                            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                        },
                        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
                        drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                            // assign it the date that was reported
                            copiedEventObject.start = date;
                            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

                            // render the event on the calendar
                            // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks"(http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                                $(this).remove();
                            }

                        },
                        events: events,

                    });
                }
                console.log('fc-event-title', document.getElementsByClassName('fc-event-title'))
            });
    }
```

i see in the console log that everything is loaded properly ,i even get the event container that gets loaded using class name fc-event-title

Comment: Maybe the `fetch()` call fails for some reason? Have you done any debugging via iOS emulator or anything like that? It's hard to tell such things just from looking at the code - especially when the same code is known to work in a different environment.

Comment: i used iphone and checked console log on it and fetch get the data and event is rendered but its not visible  and the same code and data works fine in android

Comment: `event is rendered but its not visible`...these two things appear to contradict each other. "Rendering" literally means "making visible". So what actually do you mean by "the event is rendered"... be specific and precise about what exactly you are observing, please

Comment: i mean by it being rendering that i can get it via java script and print it to console via                  console.log('fc-event-title', document.getElementsByClassName('fc-event-title'))
 but i cant actually see it with my eyes i tried  different iphones